# Cannot Inspect Element for Webpage

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, debugging, console

I am trying to in inspect element for a webpage https://supremenewyork.com, every time I try to inspect element the site crashes and I get a debugger paused exception in any browser I try, why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have the keyword debugger as `debugger;` somewhere in their code that gets executed through a condition whenever the web page is inspected, which has the same functionality as setting a breakpoint in the debugger, but you can easily click `Deactivate breakpoints` then click `Resume script execution` which should bypass that.